# Compile Error - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compilation

I have try to reprogram aspx to cshtml in MVC and Error that shows is:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0115: 'ASP._Page_Views_User_Index_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override

Source Error:


Line 59:         }
Line 60:         
Line 61:         public override void Execute() {
Line 62: BeginContext("~/Views/User/Index.cshtml", 80, 14, false);
Line 63:
```

I have no idea what is this error... Any ideas...

Comment: It is syntax error in your view "~/Views/User/Index.cshtml". It is run time compiled so it won't raise error in build time. Double check the view and see if there's anything red.

Comment: I get the feeling you tried to use a mvc view as a webforms codebehind. AFAIK in a razor view you can't define methods or classes